# Trouble installing Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed these instructions exactly:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

I've tried changing the `Download from:` setting in `Software & Updates`  from `Main Server` to `Server for United States`.

If I use `Main Server`, I get an unmet dependencies error and `ros-kinetic-desktop` `ros-kinetic-perception` `ros-kinetic-simulators` `ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial` are not going to be installed.

If I use `Server for United States`, I get `404` errors for several files and the install won't complete:

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgles2-mesa_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-bin_1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-dev_1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mir/libmircore-dev_0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mir/libmircommon-dev_0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mir/libmircookie2_0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mir/libmircookie-dev_0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mir/libmirclient-dev_0.26.3+16.04.20170605-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libegl1-mesa-dev_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgles2-mesa-dev_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

`E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]`

Everything else appears to install. Are these libs necessary?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273088/trouble-installing-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [crashtest84](https://answers.ros.org/users/32260/crashtest84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are weird errors. all of the 404s are not ros specific. Perhaps you should go back to the factory settings for the ubuntu repos. When using the Main server, can you output the full error, and ensure that sudo apt update works without error?

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crashtest84](https://answers.ros.org/users/32260/crashtest84/) on 2017-10-15**:
I think that actually answers my question. I have a horribly botched install of NVIDIA's CUDA toolkit that I haven't cleaned up yet. `apt-get update` fails because of this. Good to know these aren't ROS-specific.